# How can I create bezier like curves instead of lines between multiple points?

Tags: audio, rust

This is a relatively complex task for me and I am not fully able to sum it up in the title.

But the problem is this:

- I created a audio visualizer that converts raw audio data to a `Vec<f32>` where the elements in the vector are ordered by ascending frequency starting with 0hz and ending with 20_000hz
- But now I have to `normalize` the vector so that the frequencies are not spaced in a linear way but logarithmically, which is more like how the human hearing works. here is the function that does this:

```rs
fn normalize(buffer: Vec<f32>, volume: f32) -> Vec<f32> {
    let mut output_buffer: Vec<f32> = vec![0.0; buffer.len()];

    let mut start_pos: usize = 0;
    let mut end_pos: usize = 0;

    for i in 0..buffer.len() {
        // FIRST HALF
        let offset: f32 = (buffer.len() as f32 / (i + 1) as f32).sqrt();
        if ((i as f32 * offset) as usize) < output_buffer.len() {
            // normalized position
            let pos: usize = (i as f32 * offset) as usize;
            // stores positions needed for filling
            start_pos = end_pos;
            end_pos = pos;

            let y = buffer[i];

            // prevent volume loss, that could occur because of 'crunching' of higher freqs
            // by only setting the value of buffer if y is bigger
            if output_buffer[pos] < y {
                output_buffer[pos] = y;
            }
        }
        // SECOND HALF
        // linear filling of the values between 
        if end_pos - start_pos > 1 && (end_pos - 1) < output_buffer.len() {
            for s_p in (start_pos + 1)..end_pos {
                let percentage: f32 = (s_p - start_pos) as f32 / ((end_pos - 1) - start_pos) as f32;

                let mut y: f32 = 0.0;
                //(output_buffer[s_p] * (1.0 - percentage) ) + (output_buffer[end_pos] * percentage);
                y += output_buffer[start_pos] * (1.0 - percentage);
                y += output_buffer[end_pos] * percentage;
                output_buffer[s_p] = y;
            }
        }
    }

    output_buffer
}
```

In the first half I am reallocating the values of the buffer to be logarithmic, but with this method a lot of values especially in the low frequency range get skipped and then it looks like this: [unfilled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XGYt.png)

```
     |
     |      |
     |      |
     |      | | | 
     |   |  | ||| 
|    |   |  | |||
+----+---+--+-+++
```

Because of that I found a way to fill in the the gaps in the second half.
now it looks like this: [filled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rz49.png)

```
     |
    :|:     |
   ::|::   :|:
  :::|::: ::|:| | 
 ::::|:::|::|:||| 
|::::|:::|::|:|||
+----+---+--+-+++
```

I reduced the amount of bars for the sake of visualisation, the real implementation has about 10 time more 'bars' so the linearity is much more visible there.

So my final problem is that instead of straight lines in between the points I want to create curves, which represent sound much better.

I need to be able to access the 'y' coordinate value of any point of the curve.

Is there any way to do this, or am I doing this totally wrong?

I created [audioviz](https://github.com/BrunoWallner/audioviz) that does all of this processing and where the code is from and [audiolizer](https://github.com/BrunoWallner/audiolizer) an application that makes use this libary combined with a GUI.

Comment: Hi Bruno. I guess bezier curves are a good choice here. The general keyword you're looking for would be _interpolation_: Given a bunch of data points, fill the "in between" with reasonable values. There's probably lots to read about bezier curves, so do you have a specific question in mind?

Comment: Thank you fore the fast response. One specific question I have in mind is, if it is possible to create multiple bezier curves out of multiple 2D Coordinates and chain them together, so that I am able to access the Y Coordinate of the curve of any X Coordinate Section. I am sorry if this is a stupid question, because I do not really know anything about bezier curves.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed possible! https://towardsdatascience.com/bézier-interpolation-8033e9a262c2

Comment: Another helpful article is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Splines](https://github.com/phaazon/splines) does solve my exact problem.
here is my implementation with added resolution control and volume normalisation, that may not be neccessary:

```rs
use splines::{Interpolation, Key, Spline};
fn normalize(buffer: Vec<f32>, volume: f32, resolution: f32) -> Vec<f32> {
    let mut output_buffer: Vec<f32> = vec![0.0; (buffer.len() as f32 * resolution ) as usize ];

    let mut pos_index: Vec<(usize, f32)> = Vec::new();

    for i in 0..buffer.len() {
        let offset: f32 = (output_buffer.len() as f32 / (i + 1) as f32 * resolution).sqrt();
        if ((i as f32 * offset) as usize) < output_buffer.len() {
            // space normalisation
            let pos: usize = (i as f32 * offset) as usize;
            
            // volume normalisation
            let volume_offset: f32 = (output_buffer.len() as f32 / (pos + 1) as f32).sqrt();
            let y = buffer[i] / volume_offset.powi(3) * 0.01;

            pos_index.push( ((pos as f32) as usize, y) );
        }
    }

    // Interpolation
    let mut points: Vec<Key<f32, f32>> = Vec::new();
    for val in pos_index.iter() {
        let x = val.0 as f32;
        let y = val.1 * volume;
        points.push(Key::new(x, y, Interpolation::Bezier(0.5)));
    }

    let spline = Spline::from_vec(points);

    for i in 0..output_buffer.len() {
        let v = match spline.sample(i as f32) {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => 0.0,
        };
        output_buffer[i] = v;
    }

    output_buffer
}
```